# Autoencoder: input shape not ok

Tags: python, autoencoder

I have a list of images that I have flattened (50*45->2250). I want to use this as input for an autoencoder.
When I 'fit' the autoencoder, I get the following error:

"Error when checking input: expected input_4 to have shape (2250,) but got array with shape (1,)"

Why is the input shape (1,) ?

```
train_images2 =[]

for im in train_images:
    im = transform.resize(im,(50,45),mode='constant',anti_aliasing=True)
    im = im[:,:,0]
    im = im/255.0
    im = im.flatten()
    train_images2.append(im)

train_images = train_images2.copy()
print(np.asarray(train_images).shape) #(792, 2250)
print(train_images[0].shape) #(2250,)


# Dimensie van de hidden encoding layer
encoding_dim = 64  
# Placeholder voor input
input_img = Input(shape=(2250))
# "encoded" representation
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
# "decoded" representation
decoded = Dense(2250, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

# Creëer de autoencoder 
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)

autoencoder.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution: 'train_images' was a list. I had to change it to an array.

train_images = np.array(train_images)